# VBA transponded Values not getting recognized by Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

So I have a VBA macro that lets me use Cells like a Userform.

What it basically does is, that it takes the `Values` of the defined `Range("E2:E11")`
and transposes them to the next BlankRow.

So with that the User can easily generate a Matrix that ranges from `C16:L100`

The VBA Code looks like this:

```
Sub NeuesKFZ()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, lastERow As Long, matchCel As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range("E2:E11").Value
 lastERow = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
 If Range("E2") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Wählen Sie ein KFZ aus!"
        Range("E2").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
 
If lastERow < 16 Then lastERow = 16
 'check if the range has not been already copied:
 Set matchCel = sh.Range("C16:C" & lastERow - 1).Find(WHAT:=sh.Range("E2").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
 
 If Not matchCel Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox(sh.Range("E2").Value & " Existiert bereits " & vbCrLf & "Sollen die Daten aktualisiert werden?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         sh.Range("C" & matchCel.Row).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End If
    
    sh.Range("E2:E11").ClearContents
    
    Exit Sub

End If
 
 sh.Range("C" & lastERow).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
 sh.Range("E2:E11").ClearContents

End Sub
```

My Problem is now that excel doesn't seem to know what kind of `values` are getting transposed to the new cells.

In my case I'm working with Dates and I want to know if a date is within the next three months.
But Excel doesn't recognize that it is working with date values.
Trying to format or delete all formatting doesn't help.

And when I'm trying to use this formula:

`=if(and(C16>=$AA16$,C16<=$AB$17),TRUE,FALSE)`

Some explenation:

`C16` is the value that got transposed by the Macro.

`AA16` and `AB16` are the starting date and end date.

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are just to give me feedback if it works or not.

It just gives me `FALSE` all the time.

Is there a way to get the Date transposed so Excel still knows that its a Date?
Or Maybe force Excel to handle those values as dates.

Comment: You write that AB16 contains the end date. but in the formula you use AB17. Purpose? Or Typo? Anyhow, I would suggest that you use named ranges for that cells

Comment: In your formula `=if(and(C16>=$AA16$,C16<=$AB$17),TRUE,FALSE)` what is `$AA16$` should be `$AA$16`?

Comment: What does *"But Excel doesn't recognize that it is working with date values."* exactly mean? Please write an error description. *"Doesn't work"* is no helpful error description. Explain what happes instead of what did you expect.

Comment: Hey sorry I was offline.

Yes $AA16$ is a Typo I meant to write $AA$16.

What happens is, after I transposed the Range E2:E11 to a Row starting at C16, Excel doesn't reckognize the transposed data as number (integers) but only as flow text (strings) which make me unable to fetch the values I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transpose Column

- I think I read somewhere that besides the size limitation, `Transpose` 'doesn't like' dates. Anyway, make the following corrections to your code and copy the function to a standard module of your workbook.

**Corrections**

- Replace `arr = sh.Range("E2:E11").Value`
  with `arr = GetRowData(sh.Range("E2:E11"))`.
- Replace `sh.Range("C" & matchCel.Row).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)`
  with `sh.Range("C" & matchCel.Row).Resize(1, UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr`.
- Replace `sh.Range("C" & lastERow).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)`
  with  `sh.Range("C" & lastERow).Resize(1, UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr`

**The Function**

```vb
Function GetRowData( _
    ByVal ColumnRange As Range) _
As Variant

    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
        
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        
        Dim rData As Variant
        
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Dim cData As Variant: cData = .Value
            ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To rCount)
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 1 To rCount
                rData(1, r) = cData(r, 1)
            Next r
        End If
        
        GetRowData = rData
    
    End With

End Function
```

### EDIT

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a 2D one-based one-row array containing the values
'               from a one-column range.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRowFromColumn( _
    ByVal ColumnRange As Range) _
As Variant
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        Dim rData As Variant
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Dim cData As Variant: cData = .Value
            ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To rCount)
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 1 To rCount
                rData(1, r) = cData(r, 1)
            Next r
        End If
        GetRowFromColumn = rData
    End With
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a 2D one-based one-column array containing the values
'               from a one-row range.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnFromRow( _
    ByVal RowRange As Range) _
As Variant
    If RowRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With RowRange.Rows(1)
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        Dim cData As Variant
        If cCount = 1 Then
            ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Dim rData As Variant: rData = .Value
            ReDim cData(1 To cCount, 1 To 1)
            Dim c As Long
            For c = 1 To cCount
                cData(c, 1) = rData(1, c)
            Next c
        End If
        GetColumnFromRow = cData
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Yes this helped very much.

I haven't even learned about functions yet. Never would've thought about that.

Thank you very much! I would ask you what the function does exactly but it probably better to figure it out myself?

Comment: Might I ask another question?

Comment: Like would that work the otherway around as well? I fail to seem to understand what the function exactly does. I wanted to implement it into my other makro as well. That makro just the cell E2 as a search criteria. It searches the column C for that value. Fetches that row and transposes it to `E3:E11`.

The thing that happens is that data I do not update manually gives me the same issue.

https://codeshare.io/EBB18K Here is the source code for that makro

Comment: It will not work the other way around. The function transposes a `one-column range` to a `one-row array`. You need to rewrite the function (e.g. `GetColumnData`) to transpose a `one-row range` to a `one-column array`. I have rewritten the whole thing and an 'other way around' version. Will post shortly.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're very kind. So you basically provided me 2 functions now that both do the same but just "vice versa" right?

Comment: Because I fail to see how to implement your functions. I'm sorryI'm very much a beginner and try to learn.

Comment: Changing `arr = sh.Range("E2:E11").Value` to `arr = GetColumnFromRow(sh.Range("E2:E11"))` still lets me get the Data from the row to the column as it should. But it still generates the same issue with the dates is there something more I need to change? The code I'm currently changing is that codeshare.io/EBB18k code.

Comment: So I found out that Ihave to change this line `sh.Range("E3:E11").Value = Application.Transpose(sh.Range(matchCel.Offset(0, 1), matchCel.Offset(0, 9)).Value)` and use your `GetColumnFromRow` `function`. But I'm really not certain how to implement. I know I'm supposed to get rid of `Application.Transpose` and use the `function` which is declared as `arr` beforehand. But all changes lead to different run time errors. MAybe you can give me a hint on what to change in the original line so it fits the `GetColumnFromRow` `function`?

Comment: Solved. I wrote
`sh.Range("E3:E11").Value = GetColumnFromRow(sh.Range(matchCel.Offset(0, 1), matchCel.Offset(0, 9))).Value` the `.Value` at the end of the `GetColumnFromRow` function caused an Error. Removed it and that fixed it